# How do I read POST parameters for a RESTful service using Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am not using JSON or anything like that.  I have a simple form to upload a file and I want to read the parameters of the form.  The code below is not working as expected.  It will not show any parameters.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("{appNum}/{docId}/file")
public Response uploadDocFile(
        @PathParam("appNum") String appNum,
        @PathParam("docId") String docId,
        @Context HttpServletRequest req)
{

    try {

        log.info("POST Parameters:");

        Enumeration e = req.getParameterNames();

        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            Object key = e.nextElement();
            log.info("Key: " + key);
            log.info("Val: " + req.getParameter(key.toString()));
        }


    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(new StatusResponse(e)).build();
    }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: The form is a normal HTML form, I know this code is correct:

Comment: are the params submitted (check with firebug)

Comment: yes, i verified with wireshark

Answer (score 23, accepted):

FYI, You need to use @FormParam.  Also make sure INPUT HTML types are using name= not id=.

Comment: I reproduced the problem on my machine. You should still be able to access the HttpServletRequest (as per http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e522 ) and I don't know why I am unable to. I've tried on multiple servlet containers so I'd be curious if someone knew why this happens.

Comment: Since I landed here when Googling. I found this to work `public Response doSomething(@Context HttpContext context)`. You can then get the request with parameters from `context`.

Answer (score 21):

I have the same problem. Using `@FormParam` annotation for individual parameters works, but reading them from `HttpServletRequest` injected through `@Context` doesn't. I also tried to get the request object/parameters through Guice using `Provider<HttpServletRequest>` and `@RequestParameters<Map<String, String[]>>`. In both cases there were no post parameters.

However, it is possible to get a map of parameters by adding a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` parameter to resource method. Example:

```
@POST
public void doSomething(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [Jersey RESTful API](https://jersey.java.net/) in JAVA you can look for [Parameter Annotations (@*Param)](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1433)

Example:

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
package yourpack;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/path_to_data")
public class DataResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String urlparam) {
        int ok = 200;
        String result = "Jersey Data resource: " + urlparam;

        return Response.status(ok).entity(result ).build();
    }
}
```

List of annotations: **@MatrixParam**, **@HeaderParam**, **@CookieParam**, **@FormParam**, **@QueryParam**, **@PathParam**

Answer (score 2):

At some point of time Jersey ContainerServlet (or other Jersey object during request processing) calls request.getInputStream() or request.getReader() which set 'usingInputStream' or 'usingReader' to TRUE. This state prevents populating of parameters map inside the request object. Something like this:

```
parseParameters() {
    if (usingInputStream || usingReader) {
        return; 
    } else {
        parametersMap.putAll({actual parameters parsing from stream})
    }
} 

Map getParametersMap() {
    return parametersMap;
}
```

Try putting a break point at the very first entry point (beginning of Jersey ServletContainer.service() method) of your application and evaluate request.getParametersMap() call. You'll get your parameters.