# Get body content using HttpServletRequest in Jersey

Tags: post, jersey

I am using Jersey 1.7 and I am trying to access the request body in my method very similar to this question:
[How do I read POST parameters for a RESTful service using Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097166/how-do-i-read-post-parameters-for-a-restful-service-using-jersey)
Body value comes in fine as email=xx@ws.com&password=test1

I tried using @Context HttpServletRequest request and tried to access the email with request.getParameter("email") but get nothing. There is nothing inside request.getparameterMap() either.

My API looks like this:
@POST
@Produces(...)
public Response getData(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password, String body, @Context HttpServletRequest request) { ....

I tried changing the position of String body and request but to no avail.

The String body gets the value perfectly fine(it is coming from an iPhone device and not through a Form Submit and so shows up in the String body). Right now, I am trying to parse the body content(email=xx@ws.com&password=test1) and get each variable like email out but that is painful.

Is there some way to get the values using request.getParameter("email") ?

Or is there any quick utility to convert the body content into String email and String password ?

TIA,
Vijay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used form parameters myself, but the docs say it should work since forever:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
    // Store the message
}
```

http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features

Comment: The call is being made from a mobile device and doesn't use a form submit(uses httpClient on Android etc).So, using x-www-form-urlencoded only works for my test example from a form submission.Thanks for your reply though.I will test and see if MultivaluedMap works.

Comment: Could you please share a sample HTTP request from this particular client?