# How to read post data in a Jersey based RESTful webservice

Tags: java, rest, curl, jersey

How do i read the data which i pass in a POST or PUT method using -d option in curl

```
curl -XPUT host:port/service -d 'some data'
```

Is there an annotation similat to like @QueryParam for query parameters?

Comment: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e174

Comment: @BrianRoach link seems to be broken?

Comment: Weird - Worked fine, but they seem to be having some issue at the moment, reloading it a couple times got it to come up. It's the official docs.

Comment: ok let me check docs in their download then, thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works for me. There is no need for any annotations.

`WebService`

```
@POST
@Path("/foo")
public void foo(String data) {
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

`Output`

```
some data
```

Similar:

[How do I read POST parameters for a RESTful service using Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097166/how-do-i-read-post-parameters-for-a-restful-service-using-jersey)

Comment: Thanks that works fine for me too :) .. wow i guess i deserve a downvote for not seeing that

Comment: I don't think you deserve a downvote, some people might have this problem too :)