# Getting an Id from Angular with Jersey

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey

I'm trying to send an ID to a Java Jersey back end.
The problem is that the console is giving me 0 instead of 1, which means that the method doesn't receive the id.

This is my angularJs $http, where i'm sending a json object id:

```
  $http({
    url: '/mav8/rest/users/getUserById',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: '{'id':1}',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

}).success(function(response){
    $scope.response = response;
}).error(function(error){
    $scope.error = error;
});
```

I have this method in my userRestService, it works but doesn't receive or read the id value. The println is typing 0 in my backendconsole.

```
 @POST
@Path("getUserById")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User getUserByIdInJSON(int id) {
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    System.out.println(id);
    return userService.getUserById();
}
```

the rest of my code is working well,I can GET a list of users etc ...

Thanks a lot if you have any idea.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097166/how-do-i-read-post-parameters-for-a-restful-service-using-jersey) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$http().get('/mav8/rest/users/getUserById?id=1').success(function(response){
    $scope.response = response;
}).error(function(error){
    $scope.error = error;
});


@GET
@Path("getUserById")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User getUserByIdInJSON(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    System.out.println(id);
    return userService.getUserById();
}
```

or

```
$http().get('/mav8/rest/users/getUserById/1').success(function(response){
    $scope.response = response;
}).error(function(error){
    $scope.error = error;
});

@GET
@Path("getUserById/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User getUserByIdInJSON(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    System.out.println(id);
    return userService.getUserById();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i will try and let you know tomorrow !

Comment: The second works very well, thank you a lot, I'm trying to build a crud and at the beggining its not that easy at all.